# Container Engine is temporarily out of capacity

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I need add a new pool to my K8S cluster, but I got the error `(gcloud.container.node-pools.create) ResponseError: code=503, message=Container Engine is temporarily out of capacity in us-central1-c. Please try a different zone or try again later.`

If I try to create in another zone, like `us-central1-b`, fail because my K8S are on `us-central1-c`.

```
gcloud container node-pools create redis-pool \
  --cluster=my-kube-cluster \
  --image-type=COS \
  --machine-type=n1-highmem-2 \
  --node-labels=pool=redis \
  --zone=us-central1-c \
  --project=my-project-id \
  --num-nodes=1
```

How to fix it?
This message https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/PAtGqxUiE0o was the only report I found but without an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Google Container Engine clusters are zonal resources. This means that they cannot be created or grow in a zone that is unavailable (down or out of capacity), as is the case with `us-central1-c` above.

Comment: How to know the available resource in a zone?

Comment: GCP doesn't have an API that will return the available resources in a zone. The only signal you get is when a zone is stocked out and new resources can't be created.